# Efficient way for finding the nodes having maximum degree of separation in a connected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am working on a graph library.It has to have a function which finds the two nodes which are most separated i.e they maximum number of the minimum number of nodes required to traverse before reaching the target node from the source node.

One naive way would be to calculate the degree of separation from each node to all other node and repeat the same for every node.

The complexity of this turns out to be `O(n^2)`.

Any better solution to this problem ?

Comment: The complexity of your approach is O(n*m), not the one you state.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev : there are n nodes and you need to check its degree of separation from every other vertex. This will be done for all n vertices.hence n^2.

Comment: @jairaj How do you manage to compute the degree of separation in O(1)?

Comment: @Khaur: Agreed its not order of 1 but would be very less ,in fact equal to number of nodes in the path.Assuming (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation) six degrees of separation to be true it will be at most 6, a constant which can well be neglected.

Comment: @jairaj The idea of six degrees of separation, to my knowledge, only applies to people and cannot be used for generic graphs.

Comment: @Dukeling: well mine is a graph for social networks ;)
None the less this means that the complexity of my aproach would be say now n^2*k , where k is the average number of steps for finding the path between two nodes.Makes it even worse !

Comment: I'm speculating a bit here, but how about: Pick any node A, Run Dijkstra's algorithm to find the furthest node B from A, Run Dijkstra again from B to find the furthest node C from B, B and C are the furthest apart nodes.

Comment: @jairaj Even if there are k steps from 1 node to the other, you still need to know which ones to pick.

Comment: @Dukeling The OP refers to degree of separation, i.e. unit cost for edges. There is no need for Dijkstra's algorithm, a simple BFS (`O(|E|)`) is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) to find all pairs shortest path. Then iterate through results and find one with the longest path.

Answer (score 0):

**Without any assumptions** on the graph, [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) is the way to go.

**If your graph is sparse** (i.e. it has a relatively few edges by node, or `|E|<<|N|^2`), then [Johnson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm) is likely to be faster.

**With unit edge weight** (which seems to be your case), a naïve approach by computing the furthest node (with [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)) for each node leads to `O(|N|.|E|)`. This can probably be improved further, but I don't see a way right now.

Comment: For completeness, Floyd-Warshall does assume that there are no negative cycles in the graph, but this is a rare case, and IMO mentioning it in the answer would have reduced its clarity.

Comment: @Kaganar I did notice it if you read my answer thoroughly, that's why I posted a new answer even though an existing one was suggesting Floyd-Warshall already.